# React-Native-Sqlite , should i make db.open db.close every query?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I am asking this , because sometimes(rarely) my query doing multiple additions.

I am opening db every page at the top.

```
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'appdb.db',createFromLocation: '~appdb.db'})
```

my query is

```
  db.transaction((tx) => {                              
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO messages (chatID,messageID,senderID,message,uri,type,date)'+ 
   'values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[this.state.chatID,data.messageID,data.senderID,data.message,data.uri,data.type,data.date], (tx, results) => {
              });
              });
```

I think about convert to this for every query

```
import db from '../Classes/db';

db.open();

db.transaction((tx) => {                              
           tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO messages (chatID,messageID,senderID,message,uri,type,date)'+ 
       'values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[this.state.chatID,data.messageID,data.senderID,data.message,data.uri,data.type,data.date], (tx, results) => {
                  });
                  });
db.close();
```